# .NET runtime handling Generic code

Tags: c#, .net, generics, runtime, ildasm

How does **.NET runtime** handle **Generic code**?

Are there special constructs in **MSIL** which enable **Generic support**?

Can it be found out using **ILDASM** or **Reflection**? If *Yes*, **How**?

Comment: Waiting for someone to answer the last part of the question

Comment: Sorry for late reply.....Yeah, you can use ILDASM but I prefer to use the Visual Studion functionality itself i.e. You can have diassembled code using "Go to Diassembly" option in right click while debugging......

Comment: @akash88 "go to disassembly" shows native code, not IL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in reading this paper: [Design and Implementation of Generics for the
.NET Common Language Runtime (pdf)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fpubs%2F64031%2Fdesignandimplementationofgenerics.pdf&ei=z75mT8KlMaSkiQKCt4GjDw&usg=AFQjCNHj4QZzkoGuCkWblz1nyezWfUPeyw)